# Proving Limit Laws Using Delta Epsilon

Tags: calculus

I need to prove that

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h) $$

How would I start This! I need some willing to discuss this to a beginner who is lost Hints and detailed explanations wanted plssss

ALSO IS Subsitution given or does it have to be stated

Comment: What is $y$ meant to be?

Comment: Yes that is intuitive but I have to be mathematically rigorous

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x+a)$.

Comment: fixed my question !!!!

Comment: It's correct now.

Comment: So How do I look at this!!

Comment: I dont know how to structure my prboblem because L=$$\lim_{h\to 0 }f(a+h)$$

Comment: Or dealing with questions like this in general

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L \iff \;\; \text{Given any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $\delta \gt 0$ such that $|x - a| \lt \delta \implies |f(x) - L| \lt \epsilon$}---(1)$$

**Hint:**

Put in a variable substitution $(x = a + h)$. How would statement $(1)$ change and what would it imply??

Comment: ath aprroaches a for (fa+h)

Comment: $$\lim_{a+h\to a} f(a+h) = \lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h) $$

Comment: variable substitution needs to be formally justified $\ddot \smile$

Comment: but is it safe just to assume this ! or is this based of a therom

Comment: @user126885: No I meant substitute for $x$ only in statement $(1)$. I'm assuming you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for a limit.

Comment: How would I justify it

Comment: $$\lim_{a+h\to a} f(a+h) = L $$

Comment: Is it $(a + h) \rightarrow a$?? Look at it carefully. How would $\left|{x - a}\right| \lt \delta$ change when $x$ is replaced by $(a + h)$??

Comment: delta greater than h

Comment: Thus allowing us to show The right hans side of the inequality ! Right?

Comment: If I am right Can I assume Susitution is a valid operation or do I have to know anther proof behind it

Comment: Yes.. But my knowledge isn't extensive. Both of us will do well to ask  @dani_s what he meant?? Do you mean the substitution should be justified in the sense the domain and range and all that should not be affected?

Comment: @dani_s: Or can we assume the function is unaffected since both neighbourhoods $|x - a| \lt \delta$ and $|h| \lt \delta$ are the same??

Comment: actually could you explain what you mean by both niehbourhoods are the same

Comment: @user126885: Like I said  my knowledge in Analysis is not great. I just finished my freshman year. I *think* substitution is alright. And that you have grasped a solution. But am a little worried about the comment from dani_s. Maybe what he meant by "variable substitution should be formally justified"  is to show that the function is unaffected by changing the variable. That is it still remains defined for all our purposes. Let's wait for a response shall we?

Comment: Sure Thanks!  then lets say if I had 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}f(x^3) $$

Comment: Would I show how the delta statements for both equations are equivilant then how would I show equivalent for epsilon

Answer (score 0):

Let us write $y=a+h$. Then, $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)=\lim_{y-a\to0}f(y)=\lim_{y\to a}f(y)$. This is the same as $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$, but with a change of variable.

You could also do it this way: Using a Taylor expansion gives
$$f(a+h)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}h^k=f(a)+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}h^k$$
As $h\to0$, $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}h^k\to0$. Therefore, $\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)=f(a)$. Since $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is $f(a)$, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)$.

Comment: Thanks for the promt answer but Im just starting Delta epsilon proofs No Where Near Taylor polynomials

Comment: @user126885 Ok. Let me see if I can change my answer.